# Creating an activity to show most up to date news stories

Tags: android, feed

I'm creating a fantasy football mobile application on Android. One of the apps activities should be a page that has the most up to date fantasy football relevant news stories or NFL news in general. I've looked into things like RSS Readers but I'm not sure that's what I want. I basically want to display what you would see if you went to Google and typed "Fantasy Football" in the news section of the search. I really am just looking for answers on where to start on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can implement it somehow in your app but It's not recommended way. For this, you have to develop an app and a back-end server as well. Your app just calls a web service from the server and shows the data to use and user. Your back-end is responsible for providing the data. Now if you updated the back-end to let's say support more information sources the data in the app is updated automatically without users have to install a new version.

For getting data on the server, You can use `public webservices`, `RSS` and also a tool like `jsoup` to download and parse other people website easily.